# How could I do make both vertices and edges in a graph moveable?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

How could I make both vertices and edges moveable like this. 
(source: https://csacademy.com/app/graph_editor/)

(In the image only nodes are movable but I would like to do this for edges as well)
[image]

```
Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
  1 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5,
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 
  3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 6,
   5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Comment: Something like this is coming in the next version of the IGraph/M package, if I ever get to it ... stay tuned!

Comment: @Szabolcs that's nice. Is there any sample so I can try now?

Answer (score 3):

Use the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` in `Graph`

```
g1 = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 -> 1, 1 -> 3}, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> {v_ :> v/10}, 
  VertexStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], White], 
  VertexLabelStyle -> Large, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

To move vertices interactively (with the edges adjusting automatically to new vertex locations), use `Show @ g1` to get a `Graphics` object which can be interactively manipulated after double-clicking on it:

```
Show @ g1
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to move the edges as you like? I tried but the edges got separated.

Comment: @hana, can't think of a simple way to get full interactivity. See [these Q/As on DynamicLocation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=DynamicLocation)  for some examples that you might find useful.